# Access Authentication

Tags: tortoisesvn

I wanna know, how I can set user name and password for each user in TortoiseSVN and I already did these steps to made repository:
- Created a file then created repository in this file.
- Changed " svnserve.conf " in conf file.
- Then set all user and them passwd in conf file.
- I changed authz to access my repository also including in conf file.

I try and try to Authentication many of users for each project but as file not Http.

I hope to someone help me in this issue.

Comment: I have a little difficulties to understand your questions. Do you want to have a user name/password per project? There is no such entity in Subversion. You can only authenticate per repository, AFAIK.

Comment: Also, since you talk about TortoiseSVN, the client software, you can also only set one username/password combination per repository there. If you have multiple users, on, say, a windows machine, you must create multiple users in windows.

Comment: thanks about that, actually I have many of projects and i wanna know how create users in specific access for each one.
and i wanna know how TortoiseSVN working in local network and in server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question, but it sounds to me like you ought to move to integrating Apache with SVN.  That will give you the ability to give users different levels of access on a per-directory basis.

Refer to the sectino **Per-Directory Access Control** in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir):

> It's possible to set up finer-grained
>   permissions using a second Apache
>   httpd module, mod_authz_svn. This
>   module grabs the various opaque URLs
>   passing from client to server, asks
>   mod_dav_svn to decode them, and then
>   possibly vetoes requests based on
>   access policies defined in a
>   configuration file.